# DRBD/pacemaker both nodes are slaves

Tags: pacemaker, drbd

I have a error with the high availability soft Pacemaker, I use it with drbd. Then the configuration, I obtain the next message with the command crm_mon :

```
Last updated: Fri Aug 26 10:57:32 2016          Last change: Fri Aug 26 17:33:11 2016 by root via cibadmin on node-primary
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node-primary (version 1.1.13-10.el7_2.4-44eb2dd) - partition with quorum
2 nodes and 3 resources configured

Online: [ node-primary node-secondary ]

virtual_ip      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node-primary
Master/Slave Set: drbd-data-sync [drbd-data]
Slaves: [ node-primary node-secondary ]"

As you see, both nodes are slaves on the resource drbd-data, so, after my research, I don't find the solution of the issue,
```

For your information, here is the logs of pacemaker/corosync :

/var/log/messages

```
"Aug 26 10:58:06 node-primary lrmd[3731]:  notice: drbd-data_monitor_60000:7464:stderr [ Error signing on to the CIB service: Transport endpoint is not connected ]
Aug 26 10:59:21 node-primary drbd(drbd-data)[7629]: ERROR: testdata: Called /usr/sbin/crm_master -Q -l reboot -v 10000
Aug 26 10:59:21 node-primary drbd(drbd-data)[7629]: ERROR: testdata: Exit code 107
Aug 26 10:59:21 node-primary drbd(drbd-data)[7629]: ERROR: testdata: Command output:
Aug 26 10:59:21 node-primary lrmd[3731]:  notice: drbd-data_monitor_60000:7629:stderr [ Error signing on to the CIB service: Transport endpoint is not connected ]"
```

/var/log/cluster/corosync.log

```
"Aug 26 10:59:06 [7653] node-primary.localdomain   crm_node:    error: get_local_nodeid: Could not get local node id from the CPG API: Access error (11)
drbd(drbd-data)[7629]:  2016/08/26_10:59:21 ERROR: testdata: Called /usr/sbin/crm_master -Q -l reboot -v 10000
drbd(drbd-data)[7629]:  2016/08/26_10:59:21 ERROR: testdata: Exit code 107
drbd(drbd-data)[7629]:  2016/08/26_10:59:21 ERROR: testdata: Command output:
Aug 26 10:59:21 [3731] node-primary.localdomain       lrmd:   notice: operation_finished:       drbd-data_monitor_60000:7629:stderr [ Error signing on to the CIB service: Transport endpoint is not connected ]
Aug 26 11:00:21 [7855] node-primary.localdomain   crm_node:    error: get_local_nodeid: Could not get local node id from the CPG API: Access error (11)
drbd(drbd-data)[7831]:  2016/08/26_11:00:36 ERROR: testdata: Called /usr/sbin/crm_master -Q -l reboot -v 10000
drbd(drbd-data)[7831]:  2016/08/26_11:00:36 ERROR: testdata: Exit code 107
drbd(drbd-data)[7831]:  2016/08/26_11:00:36 ERROR: testdata: Command output:
Aug 26 11:00:36 [3731] node-primary.localdomain       lrmd:   notice: operation_finished:       drbd-data_monitor_60000:7831:stderr [ Error signing on to the CIB service: Transport endpoint is not connected ]"
```

Here is the drbd log :

```
`<cib crm_feature_set="3.0.10" validate-with="pacemaker-2.3" epoch="12" num_updat                                                                             es="14" admin_epoch="0" cib-last-written="Thu Sep  1 10:24:11 2016" update-origi                                                                             n="node-secondary" update-client="cibadmin" update-user="root" have-quorum="1" d                                                                             c-uuid="1">
  <configuration>
    <crm_config>
      <cluster_property_set id="cib-bootstrap-options">
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-have-watchdog" name="have-watchdog" va                                                                             lue="false"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-dc-version" name="dc-version" value="1                                                                             .1.13-10.el7_2.4-44eb2dd"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-infrastructure" name="cluster-                                                                             infrastructure" value="corosync"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-cluster-name" name="cluster-name" valu                                                                             e="drbd_cluster"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-stonith-enabled" name="stonith-enabled                                                                             " value="false"/>
        <nvpair id="cib-bootstrap-options-no-quorum-policy" name="no-quorum-poli                                                                             cy" value="ignore"/>
      </cluster_property_set>
    </crm_config>
    <nodes>
      <node id="1" uname="node-primary"/>
      <node id="2" uname="node-secondary"/>
    </nodes>
    <resources>
      <primitive class="ocf" id="virt_ip" provider="heartbeat" type="IPaddr2">
        <instance_attributes id="virt_ip-instance_attributes">
          <nvpair id="virt_ip-instance_attributes-ip" name="ip" value="10.44.16.                                                                             59"/>
          <nvpair id="virt_ip-instance_attributes-cidr_netmask" name="cidr_netma                                                                             sk" value="21"/>
        </instance_attributes>
        <operations>
          <op id="virt_ip-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" timeout=                                                                             "20s"/>
          <op id="virt_ip-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeout="2                                                                             0s"/>
          <op id="virt_ip-monitor-interval-10s" interval="10s" name="monitor"/>
        </operations>
      </primitive>
      <master id="drbd_data_clone">
        <primitive class="ocf" id="drbd_data" provider="linbit" type="drbd">
          <instance_attributes id="drbd_data-instance_attributes">
            <nvpair id="drbd_data-instance_attributes-drbd_resource" name="drbd_                                                                             resource" value="testdata"/>
          </instance_attributes>
          <operations>
            <op id="drbd_data-start-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="start" time                                                                             out="240"/>
            <op id="drbd_data-promote-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="promote"                                                                              timeout="90"/>
            <op id="drbd_data-demote-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="demote" ti                                                                             meout="90"/>
            <op id="drbd_data-stop-interval-0s" interval="0s" name="stop" timeou                                                                             t="100"/>
            <op id="drbd_data-monitor-interval-10s" interval="10s" name="monitor                                                                             "/>
          </operations>
        </primitive>
        <meta_attributes id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes">
          <nvpair id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes-master_max" name="master_m                                                                             ax" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes-master-node-max" name="mas                                                                             ter-node-max" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes-clone-max" name="clone-max                                                                             " value="2"/>
          <nvpair id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes-clone-node-max" name="clon                                                                             e-node-max" value="1"/>
          <nvpair id="drbd_data_clone-meta_attributes-notify" name="notify" valu                                                                             e="true"/>
        </meta_attributes>
      </master>
    </resources>
    <constraints/>
    <rsc_defaults>
      <meta_attributes id="rsc_defaults-options">
        <nvpair id="rsc_defaults-options-resource-stickiness" name="resource-sti                                                                             ckiness" value="100"/>
      </meta_attributes>
    </rsc_defaults>
  </configuration>
  <status>
    <node_state id="1" uname="node-primary" in_ccm="true" crmd="online" crm-debu                                                                             g-origin="do_update_resource" join="member" expected="member">
      <transient_attributes id="1">
        <instance_attributes id="status-1">
          <nvpair id="status-1-shutdown" name="shutdown" value="0"/>
          <nvpair id="status-1-probe_complete" name="probe_complete" value="true                                                                             "/>
        </instance_attributes>
      </transient_attributes>
      <lrm id="1">
        <lrm_resources>
          <lrm_resource id="virt_ip" type="IPaddr2" class="ocf" provider="heartb                                                                             eat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virt_ip_last_0" operation_key="virt_ip_start_0" oper                                                                             ation="start" crm-debug-origin="build_active_RAs" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" trans                                                                             ition-key="7:7:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transition-magic="0:0;7:7                                                                             :0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-primary" call-id="6" rc-c                                                                             ode="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472739600" last-rc-change="1472739                                                                             600" exec-time="52" queue-time="0" op-digest="39b1ba53e0441cc0c307a4842f021a16"/                                                                             >
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virt_ip_monitor_10000" operation_key="virt_ip_monito                                                                             r_10000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="build_active_RAs" crm_feature_set                                                                             ="3.0.10" transition-key="8:7:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transition                                                                             -magic="0:0;8:7:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-primary" c                                                                             all-id="7" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="10000" last-rc-change="1472739600                                                                             " exec-time="34" queue-time="0" op-digest="cb43afd49faa0fa13e9a578ba0eb96f6"/>
          </lrm_resource>
          <lrm_resource id="drbd_data" type="drbd" class="ocf" provider="linbit"                                                                             >
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_last_failure_0" operation_key="drbd_data_m                                                                             onitor_0" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_                                                                             set="3.0.10" transition-key="5:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transit                                                                             ion-magic="0:8;5:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-primary                                                                             " call-id="12" rc-code="8" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472739851" last                                                                             -rc-change="1472739851" exec-time="15085" queue-time="0" op-digest="cb1c1281eec7                                                                             e6bf06e0cd1385ce89d9"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_last_0" operation_key="drbd_data_demote_0"                                                                              operation="demote" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0.1                                                                             0" transition-key="9:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transition-magic                                                                             ="0:0;9:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-primary" call-i                                                                             d="14" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472739866" last-rc-chan                                                                             ge="1472739866" exec-time="36" queue-time="0" op-digest="cb1c1281eec7e6bf06e0cd1                                                                             385ce89d9"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_monitor_10000" operation_key="drbd_data_mo                                                                             nitor_10000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_featu                                                                             re_set="3.0.10" transition-key="11:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" tr                                                                             ansition-magic="0:0;11:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-                                                                             primary" call-id="16" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="10000" last-rc-change=                                                                             "1472739881" exec-time="15058" queue-time="0" op-digest="a272c0f296d99478464e690                                                                             82b608c2c"/>
          </lrm_resource>
        </lrm_resources>
      </lrm>
    </node_state>
    <node_state id="2" uname="node-secondary" crmd="online" crm-debug-origin="do                                                                             _update_resource" in_ccm="true" join="member" expected="member">
      <transient_attributes id="2">
        <instance_attributes id="status-2">
          <nvpair id="status-2-shutdown" name="shutdown" value="0"/>
          <nvpair id="status-2-probe_complete" name="probe_complete" value="true                                                                             "/>
        </instance_attributes>
      </transient_attributes>
      <lrm id="2">
        <lrm_resources>
          <lrm_resource id="virt_ip" type="IPaddr2" class="ocf" provider="heartb                                                                             eat">
            <lrm_rsc_op id="virt_ip_last_0" operation_key="virt_ip_monitor_0" op                                                                             eration="monitor" crm-debug-origin="build_active_RAs" crm_feature_set="3.0.10" t                                                                             ransition-key="6:7:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transition-magic="0:7                                                                             ;6:7:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-secondary" call-id="5                                                                             " rc-code="7" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472743200" last-rc-change="1                                                                             472743200" exec-time="49" queue-time="0" op-digest="39b1ba53e0441cc0c307a4842f02                                                                             1a16"/>
          </lrm_resource>
          <lrm_resource id="drbd_data" type="drbd" class="ocf" provider="linbit"                                                                             >
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_last_failure_0" operation_key="drbd_data_m                                                                             onitor_0" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_                                                                             set="3.0.10" transition-key="7:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transit                                                                             ion-magic="0:0;7:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-seconda                                                                             ry" call-id="10" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472743451" la                                                                             st-rc-change="1472743451" exec-time="15058" queue-time="0" op-digest="cb1c1281ee                                                                             c7e6bf06e0cd1385ce89d9"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_last_0" operation_key="drbd_data_monitor_0                                                                             " operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_feature_set="3.0                                                                             .10" transition-key="7:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" transition-magi                                                                             c="0:0;7:9:7:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-secondary" call                                                                             -id="10" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="0" last-run="1472743451" last-rc-ch                                                                             ange="1472743451" exec-time="15058" queue-time="0" op-digest="cb1c1281eec7e6bf06                                                                             e0cd1385ce89d9"/>
            <lrm_rsc_op id="drbd_data_monitor_10000" operation_key="drbd_data_mo                                                                             nitor_10000" operation="monitor" crm-debug-origin="do_update_resource" crm_featu                                                                             re_set="3.0.10" transition-key="14:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" tr                                                                             ansition-magic="0:0;14:10:0:877587e4-bfb4-47f7-8b57-56ade8f208ce" on_node="node-                                                                             secondary" call-id="13" rc-code="0" op-status="0" interval="10000" last-rc-chang                                                                             e="1472743482" exec-time="15054" queue-time="0" op-digest="a272c0f296d99478464e6                                                                             9082b608c2c"/>
          </lrm_resource>
        </lrm_resources>
      </lrm>
    </node_state>
  </status>
</cib>
```

and corosync log :) :

```
totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    cluster_name: drbd_cluster
    transport: udpu
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: node-primary
        nodeid: 1
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: node-secondary
        nodeid: 2
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    two_node: 1
}

logging {
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
}
```

Can you help me with this issue ?

Thanks for your help,

Geoffroy

Comment: Please post your Pacemaker configuration so we can see how you defined the master/slave resource.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your answer, Here is the configuration file : /etc/corosync/corosync.conf :


`totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    cluster_name: drbdcluster
    transport: udpu
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: node-primary
        nodeid: 1
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: node-secondary
        nodeid: 2
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    two_node: 1
}

logging {
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
}`

Comment: That's your Corosync configuration. Please try either, "# crm configure show > cib.txt",  or "# pcs cluster cib cib.xml". Also please edit your question and paste the configuration in there; comments aren't easy to format/read (as you can tell by the edit history on this comment).

Comment: Hi,

I update my post with the informations,

Thanks for your help,

Geoffroy

Comment: Hello,

Nobody can't help me ?

Comment: What you have labeled as "drbd log" is your Pacemaker configuration, and it's completely unreadable. I don't want to decipher the garbled XML you provided, and I doubt many others would either. Let me know if you clean it up and I will take another look.

Comment: Hello, the issue was resolved, the incident came of the compatibility between drbd and pacemaker, for your information, I join the procedure : http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/. 
Thanks for your help